# How do I respond to よろしくお願いします after being assigned a task at work?

Tags: word-choice, usage, expressions, politeness

My supervisor at work tells me よろしくお願いします after she gives me a task to do in the office. What is the appropriate way to respond? I've looked around on the internet but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common reply would be:

> 「承知{しょうち}いたしました。」

In a company with a very informal corporate culture, however, you might instead say:

> 「分{わ}かりました。」

Only you know how formally or informally your colleagues speak to their bosses.

Comment: How about 「了解」? My (Japanese) colleagues often use one of 「了解です/しました」in our fairly informal workplace and team chat. (Though I also see 「承知いたしました。」on occasion)

Comment: @muru In principle 了解 shouldn't be used toward a supervisor but I have seen many young Japanese workers using it casually (usually before getting reprimanded by their supervisor though).